# Adding cells in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i add cell in specific column for each row in gridview,i want to use  ***RowCreated*** Events.

i have gridview that has 3 columns (ProductName, Price, Count) i get (ProductName, Price) from database, and i want to add value for (count), ex: (Kitkat, 2$ ) i want to add number 5 to (count) column, i want to handle this operation when each row created.

Thanks

Comment: can you show me an image, where will be what you want?

Comment: There is not a RowCreated event.  There is a RowDataBound event.  But you probably don't want to add this as a cell, you just want to add a whole column to the GridView, then fill it in during the RowDataBound event.  Right?

Comment: i have gridview that has 3 columns (ProductName, Price, Count) i get (ProductName, Price) from database, and i want to add value for (count), ex: (Kitkat, 2$ ) i want to add number 5 to (count) column, i want to handle this operation when each row created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't shown your markup, I'm going to assume (based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106928/adding-cells-in-gridview/10107636#comment12949154_10106928)) that the first two columns are `<BoundFields>`.  If that's the case, I would add a third column as a `<TemplateField>`, place a `Label` in it, and use the `RowDataBound` event to add the correct number to the `Label`.

Here is what the markup would look like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Count">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="countLbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

And the code-behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    Label countLbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("countLbl");
    //Your logic for what number to use should go here, I'm just defaulting to 5.
    countLbl.Text = "5";
}
```

Comment: `FindControl` traverses down the `Row`. You do not need to (and should not) specify `Cells` like this.

Comment: @jwiscarson I actually did not know that, so thank you!  I can update the answer.  But why do you say "(and should not)"?  Just in case the number of / order of columns change, or something else?  I'm just curious on that last part.

Comment: Yes -- if you alter the column order or move your `Label` to another column, it'll break (aka "tight coupling"). If you're just referencing the `Row`, it's less likely to break (aka "loose(r) coupling").